# View multiple URLs using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, perl

This is the script below which has Perl, jQuery and HTML:

```
my %data = ( 1 => "http://www.google.com" , 2 => "http://www.yahoo.com" );

foreach my $website (values %data) {
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-content="$data->{$website}" class="website">Website</a>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $ = jQuery,
    $( '.website' ).popover({
        'trigger'   : 'hover',
        'placement' : 'right'
    });
});
</script>
```

When I hover on "Website", it displays 2 URL's "http://www.google.com" and "http://www.yahoo.com".

But what I want is - when I click on "Website", it should display both the URLs and then when I click on any of the URLs, it should open in a new tab. As I am very new to jQuery, can anyone please help me how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does setting your href to be `$data->{$website}` and adding `target="_blank"` suit your requirements?

Comment: Yes. That should be fine

Comment: Any problem Dean Ward?

Comment: Anything wrong in my code, please please help

Comment: I'm confused - does adding the href and target attributes not work? I added a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/C99TF/) to demonstrate the output and it works fine...

Comment: If you think my code is wrong, Is it possible to correct it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/C99TF/1/) fiddle? If so then your code just needs to be updated as follows:

```
my %data = ( 1 => "http://www.google.com" , 2 => "http://www.yahoo.com" );

<a href="#" id="popover" data-title="Websites">
    Click me!
</a>

<div id="popoverTemplate" class="collapse">
    foreach my $website (values %data) {
        <a href="$data->{$website}" target="_blank">$data->{$website}</a>
    }
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#popover").popover({
            html : true, 
            content: function() {
                  return $("#popoverTemplate").html();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This basically uses a link as the source of the popover and then an HTML template containing your list of sites as the content.

Comment: <a href="#" id="popover" data-title="Websites">
    Click me!
</a>

<div id="popoverTemplate" class="collapse">
    foreach my $website (values %data) {
        <a href="$data->{$website}" target="_blank">$data->{$website}</a>
    }
</div> can these be simplified in one <a href>?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - do you want one href for multiple websites?